# Samba Ubuntu Android no acces

Tags: ubuntu, samba

Hi I want to share files from Android with my Ubunut via WLAN

```
● smbd.service - Samba SMB Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/smbd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-06-22 10:10:05 CEST; 8min ago
       Docs: man:smbd(8)
             man:samba(7)
             man:smb.conf(5)
    Process: 67871 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/samba/update-apparmor-samba-profile (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 67880 (smbd)
     Status: "smbd: ready to serve connections..."
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 16539)
     Memory: 9.3M
        CPU: 237ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/smbd.service
             ├─67880 /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group
             ├─67882 /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group
             ├─67883 /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group
             └─67884 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/samba-bgqd --ready-signal-fd=45 --parent-watch-fd=11 --debuglevel=0 -F
```

drwxrwxrwx  2 nikki nikki 4096 Jun 22 09:37 ./

drwxrwxrwx  3 nikki nikki  4096 Jun 22 10:02 austauschtest/

here is the samba config file

https://justpaste.it/a2od1

on my phone I want to connect with a filemanager
the created directories show up, but when tapping inside them I have no real access. E.g. I cant create files or directories.
There must be some right mistake...

Comment: nobody knows whats up?

Comment: Is this really related to programming? If not, please move your problem to serverfault.com